# how to get the name of the current fragment in android?

Tags: java, android, kotlin

Excuse my ignorance but I'm a little distressed...

I would like to have some way of getting the name of the current fragment that is being displayed on the user's screen from a broadCastReceiver or else from a Service class.

currently my broadCast is activated from an alarmManager, where when it is activated it turns on a service to run a feature X...
but now I would like him to identify which is the current screen that is being displayed to the user, from this then I can perform another particular function.

I currently have a function that works perfectly on activity and fragments
that would be something like this:

```
val currentDisplay = navController.currentDestination?.displayName.toString()
```

if there is something like what I can do on broadCasts or Service it would help me a lot...

Comment: You can maintain a string in the service class and whenever your `navController.currentDestination` changes you can fire a `Broadcast` to the service class. and update the current fragment name.

Comment: Usually, there is no UI when you have a service running, so there is no fragment in that case. Similarly, when an `AlarmManager` event fires, it is unlikely that you have a UI. So, you should start by assuming that there is no "current screen that is being displayed to the user". Plus, depending on circumstances, there might be more than one fragment on the screen, anyway.

Comment: What you can do is have your `BroadcastReceiver` work with a suitable repository, to have the repository update some state and notify interested viewmodels via a reactive API (e.g., `StateFlow` or `SharedFlow` in Kotlin). Those viewmodels, in turn, can notify their associated fragments in a lifecycle-aware fashion.

Comment: Thanks for the comments, I'm actually built an application a little different from the common one... and that there are services working in the background where the user can be or not with the app open, and I have the situation where he is with the app open, I need to get the current fragment and depending on what you need to enable/disable some services and perform other functionalities...

Comment: about navController.currentDestination is there any onChangeListener for that?
How can I observe the changes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Send local broadcast from service and listen broadcast in your Activity and set some static variable as per open/selected fragment name, then from service read the value of static variable to know the set fragment name.

Or send broadcast from activity back and listen in service.